# Scales and corresponding Chords

Tags: theory, chords, scales

I am learning to play a keyboard(Noob stage) and I am reading a book regarding the same.
It is written that a scale is basically a **TONE TONE SEMITONE TONE TONE TONE SEMITONE** pattern so if I want to play in **D** scale the immediate notes after **D** would be E and F and so on for that particular scale.
 Did I get it right or am I wrong?
if That is right then are the chords different for different scales?
like what will the C-chord in D scale look like?

Thank you

Comment: Not sure what you mean by what does the c chord in d scale look like...

Comment: @DrMayhem Sorry i myself am confused much, What I meant was that in simple C scale (That starts from Middle C) the C chord is made up of C,E and G notes, what notes is C chord in D scale made up of ?

Comment: C chord is made up of C, E and G. That is what a C is.

Comment: If you have a look at some of the questions in the sidebar to the right, they may help, such as http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/12378/chords-triads-in-any-scale?rq=1 and http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/26762/chords-built-on-different-scales?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

Using your scale gives D E F# G A B C# as there is only a semi tone between E and F.

Also, this is only one scale (D Major) - there are other scales in D, such as D minor: D E F G A Bb C.

Have a read of our [modes](/questions/tagged/modes) and [scales](/questions/tagged/scales) tags for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You're absolutely right that a *major* scale follows the **T-T-ST-T-T-T-ST** pattern.  Therefore, as DrMayhem said, if you want to play a major scale in D major, it would be **D E F# G A B C# D**.  It could be useful to note that there are actually patterns in all the various scales:

- Harmonic minor: **T-ST-T-T-ST-*T+ST*-ST** (Note the T+ST is one unit)
- Melodic minor: **T-ST-T-T-T-T-ST** on the way up and **T-T-ST-T-T-ST-T**
- Natural minor: **T-ST-T-T-ST-T-T**
- Major: **T-T-ST-T-T-T-ST**
- Chromatic: **ST-ST-ST-ST-ST-ST-ST-ST-ST-ST-ST-ST**  :)

Answer (score 0):

To clarify, there is technically not a C major chord (C-E-G) in the D major scale.  one can play a C major chord in a D major context however, and in such a case the C chord would be considered chromatic.

There is a C# diminished chord (please note a C# dim. chord is in no functional way related to a C major chord) in the D major scale.  It would be C#-E-G.